# nservicebus useage based on syncronous calls or reliable low response time calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, nservicebus

I got stuck with an approach that the team and I am trying to employ and are not sure if it is the correct way of looking at the problem.

The problem is:

We have a web application with multiple WCF services running in the background. Think of it as Process 1, process 2, process 3 and process 4.

Now the scenario is that we would be invoking the process 1 from a UI call from the Web.

Process 1 would do some processing and then on success send message to process 2 using NServiceBus.

Process 2 will do some processing of its own and then send a message for process 3 to execute and on success process 3 would be returning the call.

Now the problem we are having is the first call is sent from our web app that means UI is waiting for a response of completion from the 3 services, is it a good idea to make the UI wait for the response?

Is it a good idea to make such calls especially using NServiceBus?

The above process is the user registration process so the user will be waiting for a reply from the server where as the UI will be stuck till we receive a response from the NServiceBus.

Should we actually be looking at NServiceBus implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone lost return button on his keyboard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing Request-Response over NServiceBus which is not a recommended use of a service bus or a message based architecture.

If you want to make use of message based architecture and need the benefits of Publish/Subscribe for something else in your system you must rethink the registration process.

I you think about it, maybe the user doesn't need to see the result straight away. Maybe you can collect information and then send it for processing and if anything goes wrong, send an email and ask the user for more info or have them do other actions. Maybe it could be a step in a account verification or something.

Comment: If you need workflow, then look into the Saga implementation.  I agree, the user communication can happen on another channel.

Comment: hi mikael, yeap i do agree with you but how do u recommend this specific registration process be handled which makes it optimum with out having to directly depend on each other. thanks

Comment: Try to figure out if the process can be split into several parts and if the user really needs to see results immediately. If you want to do this asynchronous you have to create a process and a UX that supports that. Maybe a Saga could help as Adam says, but in the end it will come down to the way the user experiences the process. Figure out ways to allow for parts in this process to be in a pending state, but don't make your users look at a spinning ajax progress indicator while you do asynchronous processing.